# Filtering a logical and symmetric matrix

Tags: r, matrix, filtering

I have a logical and symmetric matrix and I want to create blocks depending on the value I have on the diagonal.
Here is my matrix:

```
MAT <- data.frame(matrix(data = c(rep(TRUE, 9), rep(FALSE, 3), rep(TRUE, 3), FALSE, rep(TRUE, 3), rep(FALSE, 2), TRUE, 
                FALSE, rep(TRUE, 2), FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, rep(TRUE, 3), FALSE, rep(TRUE, 4)), 6))

 [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]
[1,] TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[2,] TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[3,] TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
[4,] TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
[5,] TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
[6,] TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Here is the desired matrix:
[image]
We can see that a block is based on TRUE values. All columns and rows must be related to each other by TRUE in order to be a block. Once we have even one FALSE there is no block. We can have a block constituted of only one column as in the fourth column.

My goal is to put the same number in each column belonging to one block as seen in the image.

Comment: I put the color only to illustrate the blocks.
I would like just to put the same number in each column belonging to one block (as in the image). I can't do that manually because I have thousands of columns

Comment: I understand that part but not clear how you expect the output. to be returned.  Do you need a list of matrix etc

Comment: I want to create row at the top of that same matrix. That row should contain block's number as in the image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question states that MAT is a matrix but, in fact, it is defined there as a data.frame.  This is important because `all(MAT)` where MAT is as defined in the question gives an error in R 4.0 but not in R 4.1 so be sure you are using R 4.1 with the code below.  Alternately convert MAT to a matrix using `MAT <- as.matrix(MAT)` in which case the code below works with both 4.1 and 4.0 and older.

**1) Loop** is.complete(i, j) is TRUE if all cells in MAT[i:j, i:j] are TRUE.  If p to i is complete and p to i+1 is not complete then p to i is a block so record i in d and then at the end find the length of each block and use rep to create the desired vector placing it in the column names since one cannot mix logical and integer values together.

```
is.complete <- function(i, j) all(MAT[i:j, i:j])

i <- p <- 1
d <- c()
for(i in 1:nrow(MAT)) {
  ok <- is.complete(p, i) && (i == nrow(MAT) || !is.complete(p, i+1) )
  if (ok) { p <- i+1; d <- c(d, i) }
}
colnames(MAT) <- rep(seq_along(d), diff(c(0, d)))
MAT
```

giving:

```
     1     1     1     2     3     3
1 TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
2 TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
3 TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
4 TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
5 TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
6 TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

**2) Reduce** Another possibility is Reduce.  We accumulate the current start of block, p.  At each step we consider the next index i and if the block from p to i is entirely TRUE then we continue p for consideration onwards; otherwise we start a new block at i.  In the end Reduce returns a vector of the start of block repeated for each row (or column) of the block.  We can then convert to factor and take the integer levels to get 1, 2, ...  This approach is compact and uses no explicit loops.

```
f <- function(p, i) if (all(MAT[p:i, p:i])) p else i
colnames(MAT) <- as.integer(factor(Reduce(f, 1:nrow(MAT), acc = TRUE)))
MAT
```

giving:

```
     1     1     1     2     3     3
1 TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
2 TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
3 TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
4 TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
5 TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
6 TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

**3) maximize cells in blocks**  The solutions so far are greedy in nature. They take the largest block and when no larger one can be found start a new block; however, if it were desired to maximize the number of cells in blocks then that might not give the maximum value.

If we regard MAT as an adjacency matrix we can convert it to a graph in which case blocks correspond to complete subgraphs, also known as cliques.  We generate all cliques and form an nrow(MAT) row matrix K with one clique per column such that each column is a 0/1 vector indicating which rows in MAT are in that clique.  If there are
p columns in that matrix then we form an objective p-vector v such that
v[i] equals sum(K[, i])^2 which is the number of cells in the block that corresponds to clique i.  From this we form the integer linear program to maximize the number of cells in blocks by choosing the 0/1 vector which satisfies:

```
max v'x such that Kx = 1 
x is 0/1 vector
```

where 1 is a vector of nrow(K) ones.  This is known as a set partitioning problem.

```
library(igraph)
cli <- cliques(graph_from_adjacency_matrix(as.matrix(MAT), mode = "undirected"))
K <- +sapply(cli, function(x) colnames(MAT) %in% names(x))

library(lpSolve)
obj <- colSums(K)^2
res <- lp("max", obj, K, "=", 1, all.bin = TRUE)
Ksoln <- K[, res$solution == 1]
o <- order(apply(Ksoln, 2, which.max))
colnames(MAT) <- Ksoln[, o] %*% 1:ncol(Ksoln)
MAT
```

giving:

```
     1     2     1     3     1     1
1 TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
2 TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
3 TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
4 TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
5 TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
6 TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

or sorting by block:

```
o <- order(as.numeric(colnames(MAT)))
MAT2 <- as.matrix(MAT)[o, o]
colnames(MAT2) <- sub("\\.*", "", colnames(MAT2))
MAT2
```

giving this reordered matrix:

```
        1     1     1     1     2     3
[1,] TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[2,] TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
[3,] TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[4,] TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
[5,] TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[6,] TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

We see that with this solution there are 18 cells in blocks

```
res$objval
## [1] 18
```

whereas for the greedy solutions there are only 3^2 + 1^2 + 2^2 = 14 cells in blocks.

**4)** In the comments the poster indicated they are interested in the variation of (3) in which the groups are constrained to be consecutive. To do that simply restrict the K matrix to those columns that represent consecutive groups, i.e. add the two lines of code involving is.consec marked with ## below.  We also use the modified input that the poster has defined in the comments below and have also marked those lines with ##.  The code is otherwise identical to (3).

```
MAT <- data.frame(matrix(data = c(rep(TRUE, 9), rep(FALSE, 3), 
  rep(TRUE, 3), FALSE, rep(TRUE, 3), rep(FALSE, 2), TRUE, 
  FALSE, rep(TRUE, 2), FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, rep(TRUE, 3), FALSE, 
  rep(TRUE, 4)), 6))
MAT<-cbind(MAT,c(TRUE,FALSE,rep(TRUE,2),FALSE,TRUE)) ##
MAT<-rbind(MAT,c(TRUE,FALSE,rep(TRUE,2),FALSE,rep(TRUE,2))) ##
MAT<-cbind(MAT,c(rep(FALSE,5),rep(TRUE,2))) ##
MAT<-rbind(MAT,c(rep(FALSE,5),rep(TRUE,3))) ##

library(igraph)
cli <- cliques(graph_from_adjacency_matrix(as.matrix(MAT), mode = "undirected"))
K <- +sapply(cli, function(x) colnames(MAT) %in% names(x))
 
is.consec <- function(x) sum(x == 1) == 1 ||  all(diff(which(x == 1)) == 1) ##
K <- K[, apply(K, 2, is.consec)] ##
 
library(lpSolve)
obj <- colSums(K)^2
res <- lp("max", obj, K, "=", 1, all.bin = TRUE)
Ksoln <- K[, res$solution == 1]
o <- order(apply(Ksoln, 2, which.max))
colnames(MAT) <- Ksoln[, o] %*% 1:ncol(Ksoln)
MAT
```

giving:

```
      1     1     1     2     3     4     4     4
1  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
2  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
3  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
4  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
5  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
6  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
7  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
8 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: Superb `Reduce` approach, upvoted for this amazing solution!

Comment: Both solutions work well, thank you @G. Grothendieck.
You are right; it was not even necessary for the purpose of this question to add `data.frame()` as I did in my question. Indeed, I just had to remove `data.frame()` and actually stay with a matrix to make it work.
Here is what I used finally: `MAT <- matrix(data = c(rep(TRUE, 9), rep(FALSE, 3), rep(TRUE, 3), FALSE, rep(TRUE, 3), rep(FALSE, 2), TRUE, FALSE, rep(TRUE, 2), FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, rep(TRUE, 3), FALSE, rep(TRUE, 4)), 6)`

Comment: Added solution (3).

Comment: Solution 3 is not really adapted to my case. I want to have the blocks consecutively and exactly in the order they appear in the matrix regardless of the number of cells at the end @G. Grothendieck

Comment: Therefore, there is a concern with the two first solutions. They give blocks consecutively regardless of whether or not they are the biggest blocks possible.
For instance, if we add two new columns and rows in to our matrix as here: `MAT<-cbind(MAT,c(TRUE,FALSE,rep(TRUE,2),FALSE,TRUE));MAT<-rbind(MAT,c(TRUE,FALSE,rep(TRUE,2),FALSE,rep(TRUE,2)));MAT<-cbind(MAT,c(rep(FALSE,5),rep(TRUE,2)));MAT<-rbind(MAT,c(rep(FALSE,5),rep(TRUE,3)))`
we notice that at the end of our matrix we had three blocks but no matter which solution we use here it is going to give two blocks. Here what I expect: 11123444

Comment: Have added (4) which addresses this variation of the problem.

Comment: @G. Grothendieck that is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the code below

```
mat <- MAT <- as.matrix(MAT)
r <- 0
while (length(mat) != 0) {
    k <- max(which(sapply(seq_along(diag(mat)), function(k) all(mat[1:k, 1:k]))))
    r <- c(r, rep(tail(r,1) + 1, k))
    mat <- as.matrix(mat[-(1:k), ][, -(1:k)])
}
colnames(MAT) <- tail(r, -1)
```

which gives

```
> MAT
        1     1     1     2     3     3
[1,] TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[2,] TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[3,] TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
[4,] TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
[5,] TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
[6,] TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```